# Event fires for all items not just the current item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to attach my plugin to a input field, and it works somewhat. So, I am attaching an `on()` with `onchange` to the input field, and when it fires, it fires for each input, and not just the one that changed. What is causing this? Is it because I am using `$(document).on()`? I added it that way because items are dynamically added to the page.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.itemsave = function(config){
    return this.each(function(){
        var item = $(this);
        var opt = {
            // The options
        };
        var e = $.extend(opt, config);
        $(document).on("change", item, function(){
            request(false, e);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

How it is called:

```
$(".simplesave").itemsave(null);
```

Comment: When using variable that is jQuery one, you should use special notation: var $item = $(this). It will avoid confusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing a jQuery object as the second parameter of `.on()`. That's not an error, but the library will interpret that as being an object to be made available to the event handler as `event.data`.  It also means that there is no event handling delegation going on. Thus, you're establishing a "change" event handler that will fire when ever any "change" event bubbles up to the document level.

You *probably* should just be attaching the handler directly to your element:

```
item.on("change", function() {
    request(false, e);
});
```

Comment: Or, shorter, `item.change(function(){...})`

Comment: @pointy: With documents.on, it should be using delegation right? It should work without putting on item also right?

Comment: @Vikash  no - delegation only happens when the second parameter is a **string**, which is taken to be a selector.

Comment: @Pointy: I see. Thanks for the clarification. Nice to learn new things :)

Comment: looks like I have to change more than just this one.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this line is causing an error as `item` should be a selector not an element:

```
$(document).on("change", item, function(){
```

The solution would be to put an even handler on the item

```
$(item).on("change", function(){
  request(false, e);
})
```